# Window Azure Mobile Service throwing Exception

Tags: android, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am using window azure mobile service to enter data into database from my android application.

Everything was working fine but when i change the key of the portal account i am using to save data , it gives me following error at the time of inserting item .

6W/System.err(9867): Caused by: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {"code":400,"error":"Error: Bad request."}

Can anyone help me out from this .

Comment: When you changed the key on the portal, did you also change the key on the application? And what exactly do you mean by "change the key of the portal account"?

Comment: No i solved it , actually it was database problem , my project admin made one the column  to set isRequired checkbox in new version . Bydefault i was sending nothing into that so it gets null value , that was the problem .

Still i like that you have give attention to my question .
I thank you for that.

Comment: Great. Can you post your comment as an answer and accept it, so other people can see what happened? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After comparing my both database versions i finally found that , if we have any columns that is checked by isRequired field than we must have to send some value there , otherwise it will give you bad request Exception .